# property "start_url" ignored,should be same origin as document

Tags: php, json, http, manifest.json

I was Usign a Cross-Domain Manifest.Json Here My Json File (located at `http://123myblog14.co.nf/manifest.json`):

```
{
  "short_name": "Universal Manual",
  "name": "Universal Manual",
  "theme_color": "#4A90E2",
  "background_color": "#F7F8F9",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jNpzwSZoHI4/Wn8trSeVxOI/AAAAAAAAAao/SJEDZypr0aw22ekaf54gP_uBc0UMIkevACLcBGAs/s320/48x48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EvJoMC9Ofio/Wn8trZJCPeI/AAAAAAAAAak/aVIfXSwRJp0ccKYpXg52ZKs6tNB2SpNDwCLcBGAs/s320/96x96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Al0F7R0hpjo/Wn8trVIOoEI/AAAAAAAAAag/5ESG8a3skgMGEhS5zVZ-5FKPHA3bWTBxQCLcBGAs/s320/144x144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-myt190wt15M/WnnH7The49I/AAAAAAAAAZY/86YIMqtB7U8cZ7wHIhFx-pgSHZVg0V5YQCPcBGAYYCw/s320/192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=launcher"
}
```

But Crome Shows Below Error in warning.

`property "start_url" ignored,should be same origin as document`

I'm usign it on My website with Https but the website where it is hosted isn't https. Is this is Reason?

Answer (score 0):

chrome sets the cross-origin header to the host name if a cross-origin header is not present, to solve this you need to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the value `*` from your website ( 123myblog14 )

you can either send the header with php like this :

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

or via .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

**update**

you can create a php file next to manifest.json like this

`manifest.php`

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo file_get_contents('manifest.json');
?>
```

and you can access manifest.json from manifest.php

Comment: did this work https://github.com/vitvad/Access-Control-Allow-Origin/blob/master/manifest.json ?

Comment: i really don't know, your question is tagged with `php`. so i answer with the php , and the second one should work too i you are using apache

Comment: It actually didn't even detecting manifest.json now after adding above code in my .htaccess file. I think this is due to https.

Comment: i found the same question asked on github : https://github.com/cargomedia/CM/issues/1712 . 
and i think the answer is to you the same hostname to serve manifest file ( same domain )

Comment: `<link rel="manifest" href="http://www.123myblog14.co.nf/manifest.php"/>` I use it as shown in this code but this doesn't work

Comment: here an website on which i testing this code but crome didn't even detecting manifest.php  https://www.universalmanual.com/

Comment: hmm, weird, seems like a chrome issue, it works fine on firefox